# Is it true that $|(Mv)\cdot(Nw) \leq C|v||w|$ (matrix-vector)?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis

If $M$ and $N$ are matrices such that each element of the matrices depends on $t$, so  we have $M_{ij}(t)$, $N_{ij}(t)$, and we have the result $M_{ij}$, $N_{ij} \in L^\infty(0,T)$, is it true that
$$(Mv)\cdot(Nw) \leq C|v|| w|$$
for two vectors $v$ and $w$?

How to see this without expansion? Thanks

Comment: Are these finite $n \times n$ matrices?

Comment: And what does $\cdot$ stand for? Dot product maybe? If that is the case then the answer is affirmative. A "soft" way of proving the result is observing that, for any bilinear form $B$ on a normed space, the condition 
$$\lvert B(v, w)\rvert\le C \lVert v \rVert \lVert w \rVert$$
for some constant $C\ge 0$ is equivalent to continuity of $B$. In the case at hand the bilinear form is defined in a finite-dimensional space and so it is automatically continuous.

Comment: Do you also want to know if $C$ can be taken independent of time $t$?

Comment: @JasonZimba Yes they are finite. Yes $C$ should be independent of $t$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes it is dot product.

Comment: Ok. By the way, my previous commentary yields a constant $C$ which depends on $t$. But it is not difficult to obtain a uniform bound, I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $\lvert M_{ij}(t)\rvert \le \sqrt{C}$ and $\lvert N_{ij}(t)\rvert\le \sqrt{C}$. We have that 
$$\begin{split}
\lvert (Mu)\cdot (Nu)\rvert &= \left\lvert \sum_{ijk} M_{ij}(t) v_j N_{ik}(t)u_k\right\rvert\\
&\le C\sum_{ijk} \lvert v_j u_k\rvert \\ 
&= C n \sum_{jk} \lvert v_j u_k\rvert \\ 
&= C n \sum_{j}\lvert v_j\rvert \sum_k\lvert u_k\rvert.
\end{split}
$$
By the Cauchy Schwarz inequality one has 
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\displaystyle 
\sum_{j}\lvert v_j\rvert \le \sqrt{n}\lvert v \rvert, &\displaystyle 
\sum_{k} \lvert u_k\rvert \le \sqrt{n} \lvert u \rvert.
\end{array}
$$
So we obtain
$$
\lvert (Mv)\cdot (Nu)\rvert \le C n^2 \lvert v\rvert \lvert u\rvert.
$$

Comment: I understand thanks